# Pantech UML290 Verizon Driver

Tags: windows, drivers, cellular

Is there a separate driver available for Pantech UML290 4G LTE USB Modem?  I would prefer not to have to install VZAccess, but use the default Windows DUN support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running the VZAccess installer for the UML290, with options to extract, the installer files will be extracted to %TEMP%{some random guid}.  I used Process Monitor to find the location, but you can also use the last modified time.  It seems like the installer may delete the files after the installer closes, so you may need to leave it open until you copy the file out.  The Pantech driver installer is named "PTUML_V1_7_107_0523.exe"

`VZAM 7.7.7.0-2767c_Pantech_UML290_Updated_Driver_MR4.exe /extract_all`

In lieu of using the stock installer, you can also copy the inf and sys files from `C:\Program Files\PANTECH\UML290` on a computer that has VZAccess installed.